# Funding situation if I have passed GATE but lack CSIR-JRF NET

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, india

I have finished my M.Sc. in Applied Mathematics in 2016. I wish to pursue a PhD. Currently I am preparing for GATE (Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering, a master’s-level national entrance exam in India). In this respect, I have a few questions.

1. If I only have a valid GATE score but no CSIR-JRF NET qualification, will I be eligible for the 25 k funding?
2. If yes to above, is this funding available for any NAAC-accredited university (public or private) in India?
3. Is there any written statement from the government which validates this?

Comment: How about explaining what all these acronyms mean?

Comment: @aparente001 : GATE is an acronym for Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering which is a masters level national entrance exam in India. CSIR, UGC, NAAC are governmental bodies which deal with higher education, research and university accreditation in India. NET stands for National Eligibility Test which is a PhD level national entrance examination in India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen any written statement, but so far I have learned and experienced the below.

Through GATE (Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering) score, you can take admission for PhD program with 25k p.m. scholarship in

```
IITs/NITs (Indian/National Institute of Technology), 
IISc (Indian Institute of Science), 
IISERs/NISERs (Indian/National Institute of Science Education and Research) 
and some other Institutes in India.
```

Through GATE, you can also take admission into PhD program with about 2000 SGD p.m. scholarship in

```
NUS (National University of Singapore) 
and NTU (Nanyang Technological University, Singapore).
```

To answer your question:

> If I only have a valid GATE score but no CSIR-JRF NET qualification,
>   will I be eligible for the 25 k funding?

Yes, but not everywhere. Please visit the webpage of the Institutes/Universities and check their instructions about scholarship or inquire via telephone or email.

> If yes to above, is this funding available for any NAAC-accredited
>   university (public or private) in India?

Not sure, may be available, but very limited.

> Is there any written statement from the government which validates
>   this?

I have never searched such written statements.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and answer. As of now, +1.. I will wait for some more time to accept this answer. Its only because, I want this thread to be open for some more time.

Answer (score 1):

Although I admit that I am not fully aware of this area, here is my 2 cents on the matter based on my limited understanding:

1. As far as I am aware the GATE exam, is a masters level entry exam. It usually fetches you around Rs.12.4k per month of government funding during a masters degree. While it *may* be used as an entrance test for a PhD in India, the funding by the government is not available during the a post master level degree. Having said that, universities might sometimes have intakes on individual project based PhDs (where basically they fund you off that project) which *might* not check if you have a NET score. Again, I say *might*.
2. Passing the NET examination indeed does make you *eligible* for the aforementioned amount in terms of government sponsored scholarship. Ofcourse, you have to send a project proposal to the actual CSIR or UGC to actually get the scholarship.
3. Funding is usually not restricted by which university you belong to, as long as it is accredited. I am not sure of any written statement that validates this however, but it should be the case.

Please do not take my word as gospel because I am from an Engineering background and things might be slightly different in my area.